# Swift: Place control based on webpage elements position

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I need to position an `UIButton` over an `UIWebView`, based on an element in the webpage.
I managed to do it using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript`.

```
let webSettingsButtonTopString : String = "document.getElementById('settingsBtn').offsetTop;"
settingsButtonTop = Int(self.wvWinfoDashboard.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: webSettingsButtonTopString)!)
lcSettingsButtonTopAlign.constant = CGFloat(settingsButtonTop)
```

The problem is this solution depends on what value `settingsButtonTop` will take. If the page fails to load or it takes too much to do so, nothing will happen.

The other solution I could think of is to manage the `UIButton` position based on the display resolution but I don't like the idea since it's not dynamic.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: You should use WKwebview

Comment: @IOSSingh - Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it's a bit too late right now since the entire app is based on webviews and it would take some time to switch.